# curl (6) couldn't resolve host (on windows for instagram API)

Tags: curl, instagram-api

I am trying to obtain an access token for the Instagram API, but when I run this code in the CMD window on windows:

```
curl -F 'client_id=IDNUMBER' curl -F 'client_secret=CODE' curl -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' curl -F 'redirect_uri=URL' curl -F 'code=CODE' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

as outlined here:

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

I get this error:

```
curl (6) couldn't resolve host
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You are replacing access_token in the url 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token' with your token correct? You will also want to do all of the cURL calls in one.

Comment: what should the full request be like then so I get this right thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got the program call wrong.

```
curl -F 'client_id=IDNUMBER' curl [...]
```

That is, you have given `curl` as a parameter to `curl`, which thinks it should look up a host named `curl`.

Remove all extra "curl" and write:

```
curl -F 'client_id=IDNUMBER' -F 'client_secret=CODE' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=URL' -F 'code=CODE' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```